# How do I Post JSON Object to a Live Website

Tags: http, post, postman

The problem is I am trying to make a POST request with my information via postman  by following the instructions below see
Application instructions
To apply send your application to:

https://********.com/about/careers/apply?data=

by setting the content of the data variable to valid JSON with the following properties:

```
name: String with your name (required)
email: String with your email address (required)
position: String with the position you are applying for (required)
urls: Array of strings with links to your resume (required), along with any personal sites, sample projects, or your Github profile
comment: String with any comment/request you might have (optional)
```

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "position" : "Software Engineer",
    "urls":[ "https://github.com/johnDoe" ],
    "comment": "na"
}
```

You will receive a 200 response on success.
 I followed the instructions using postman, setting the content type to application-json but it returns with the Error; no data passed. HTTP 400 Bad Request

[image]  but then get this

Comment: please read [mcve] and provide the missing details, your question is not understandable enough

Answer (score 0):

To post JSON data to APIs, most servers expect a valid `content-type: application/json` header.

More info on content type header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type